# How mule invoke the component?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

After go through some guides about [Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/), I have a question about the component, as it is said in mule documentation,

> A simple POJO (Plain Old Java Object) component that will be invoked
>   by Mule when a message is received. The class or object instance to be
>   used can be specified using a child object factory element, or via the
>   'class' attribute.  If the 'class' attribute is used, an object
>   factory cannot be configured as well. Using the 'class' attribute is
>   equivilant to using the propotype object factory ('prototype-object'
>   child element).

in this documentation just said the component will be invoked by Mule when a message is received, but a problem is Mule how to know how many methods the component have, and which method should be invoked? or there must one method in the component and no matter the method name? and also mule how to deal with the parameters the method have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use:

```
<invoke object-ref="..." method="..."  methodArguments="..." />
```

which is way more convenient than configuring entry point resolvers.

Comment: Hi David, I did some try, and finally fail with mule 3.4.0. and then I tried google it and found some result in stackoverflow, and another result is [MULE-5179](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5179) where seems you added a comment about the <invoke/> element. but this ticket still reopened and do you know what's the fate of <invoke/> now? and if there is some example is appreciated.

Comment: Invoke is here to stay. It works fine with Mule 3.4.0 so please open a new question showing the failing config and the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I got the answer, the answer is using [mule entry point](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-school-invoking-component-methods-using-entry-point-resolvers/)